# Why when updating app all achievements are shown?

Tags: ios, game-center, achievements

Whenever I update my iOS app or when I open it after not using it for awhile every completed achievement is shown one after the other. This must be a very unusual issue because I have not found any info about it anywhere. What is solution to this? Anyone? Thanks.

PS: the app is on App Store

Comment: Which app? One you wrote?  What achievements? Game Center achievements?  How do you display those achievements?

Comment: Yes it's my app. Game center achievements as noted in the tags and displayed with banners.

Comment: Also code is objc